# What is the correct way to load in object in emberjs?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Let me first describe my usecase.

As a user, you should be able to create a job, while creating this job, you need to specify a field of work. These fields should be loaded dynamically from my REST API.
Being quite new to EmberJS i don't really now how i should load in these fields, as i am working in the JobNewController & route.

Should i somehow load them in my route? I have been trying something like this, but i can't get it to work, also i not quite sure what i am doing anyway.

```
MyApp.JobsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller) ->
    controller.set 'serviceFields', MyApp.ServiceField.find()
```

Using this template

```
<p>Creating a new job</p>
<div class="ui input">

  Select a service field
  {{#each serviceFields }}
    {{name}}   sdf
  {{/each}}

</div>
```

I also tried doing this in the controller like so.

MyApp.JobsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  serviceFields: MyApp.ServiceField.find()

But this yields and error

```
Assertion failed: Your application does not have a 'Store' property defined. Attempts to call 'find' on model classes will fail. Please provide one as with 'YourAppName.Store = DS.Store.extend()'
```

I guess the controller code is ran before the Store is initialized.

How should i handle this?

Comment: Are you using Ember model or Ember Data (or neither)?

Comment: EmberData, within the Rails-ember gem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to get models is to use the store and find that model type. (pardon my coffeescript, I used a converter to do it for me)

```
MyApp.JobsRoute = Ember.Route.extend(setupController: (controller, model) ->

  # return does nothing here
  # this._super(controller,model); would do the default
  controller.set "serviceFields", []
  promise = @get("store").find("serviceField")
  promise.then (records) ->
    controller.set "serviceFields", records

)
```

This is the more common approach, btw

```
MyApp.JobsRoute = Ember.Route.extend(model: ->
  @get("store").find "serviceField"
)
```